# How can i make a tabular fit the page width with the text centered?

Tags: tables

I want to create a table that will be as wide as the page.
I used this code :

```
\begin{tabular}{|l@{\hspace{7pt}}|c@{\hspace{50pt}}|c@{\hspace{80pt}}|}
 \hline Τ1 & Triangle Inequallity & $ \beta-\gamma<a<\beta+\gamma $ \\ 
 \end{tabular}
```

But the text is not centered.
Is there a way to fit the page automatically with the text centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the `tabularx` package and defining a new column such that the text is centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} X}

{\par\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|C|C|}
\hline T1 & Triangle Inequallity & $ \beta-\gamma<a<\beta+\gamma$ \\
\end{tabularx}

\par}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `showframe`to show that the table does fit the text width. Change the margins with the `geometry` package to test with other widths.
[image]

Comment: Since the `tabularx` environment is set to be as wide as `\textwidth`, there's no need to insert the `\centering` command. Also, the two `\par` statements do nothing at the moment since they're preceded by *and* succeeded by empty lines, which also generate paragraph breaks. It might be cleanest to provide a single `\noindent` statement before `\begin{tabularx}...`.

Comment: @Mico but the OP wants the text to be centered, if you remove `\centering` (i.e. a plain `X` column) the text is not centered anymore. If instead you mean the `{\par\centering ... \par}` stuff, without that the table results indented, since my MWE uses the `article` class.

Comment: @Mico, for some reason I'm seeing your full comment only now. I prefer not to use `\noindent`, the code looks much cleaner this way to my eyes. Also I thought that the `{\par\centering` stuff may have been more useful to the OP (also to understand what's going on in the code). Oh, and the empty lines are for clarity :)

Comment: Sorry about not having been sufficiently clear *which* `\centering` instruction I was referring to as being unneeded: Indeed, it was the one *after* `\par` and *before* `\begin{tabularx}`. I suppose the `\centering` instruction is not entirely superfluous, because it serves to undo the paragraph indent that LaTeX would otherwise insert. (However, the two `\par` statements are indeed superfluous.) Based on my personal aesthetics, I think it may be more conducive to understand what's going on if the paragraph indent is undone explicitly via `\noindent` rather than implicitly via `\centering`.

Comment: @Mico I see what you mean but as I said, the `\par` stuff may be useful to the OP if he uses this code in a more complex document, so I used the version I thought would have been more useful for the OP, indipendently of the actual MWE.